# Sending Array From Android To Server Side via Post Request

Tags: android, arrays, post, request, server

Good day.Im sending post request to php server side like this

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("my server name");

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        /*StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(from.getText().toString(), "-");
        String shortstring = tokens.nextToken();
        String longstring = tokens.nextToken();
        StringTokenizer tokens2 = new StringTokenizer(to.getText().toString(), "-");
        String shortstringto = tokens2.nextToken();
        String longstringto = tokens2.nextToken();*/

        try {
            reqEntity.addPart("type", new StringBody("3"));
```

Server side receives it like this

```
   Array
    (

    [type] => 3


)
```

All seems good which afar he wants me to send to him an array.I do send it like this

```
     ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList();
       aray.add("hello");
 reqEntity.addPart("array", new StringBody(array.toString()));
```

he receives it like this

```
 Array
    (

    [type] => 1
    [array]=> [hello];



)
```

All seems good but he assumes thats  I'm sending wrong and he wants the array to be send so he can receive it like this way.

```
 Array
        (

        [type] => 1
        [array]=> Array(
                    [header name of my array]=>"value of array"

                    )



    )
```

I google every bit i read every single line of every site,and did not found anything even close to what he wants as if i send array it will be like i wrote,otherwise he just wants array of inside another array with KEY name of inner array and with VALUE of inner array,which i don't know but somehow not possible for my opinion in the way he wants.So is it possible?can i send array the way he wants in my last written code?

Comment: `DefaultHttpClient is deprecated`, use `HttpUrlConnection` instead. Second its very unclear what you are asking, you must change to JSON from ArrayList if its so complicated.

Comment: here is what my co-worker wants,i really don't understand him so i came here,anyway i don't worry about deprecation as it never  hits me,so it seems that whenever i send some request with properties to server side,he receives it with ARRAY() way,and he wants to receive it inside property too,which i said in my last part,so he wants to receive array from me like he do receive it when i make post request with properties,and he don't want to receive JSON:(like what the hell to do?

Comment: It would be better to change to JSON, without the complete problem specs we cant help!

Comment: Thats the problem,its matter like this,if i send some array without json he receives it like this [somearrayname]=>some value,but instead of this way he said to me that i must send real array so he will receive it like ARRAY ( [somearrayname]=>"some array value" ) so whats matter?i can't understand him

Comment: You can send him a JSON array, [Refer to this page](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)

Comment: he says that i must send and he don't want me to send json array:(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry don't have enough points to post a comment. But you need to provide a little more information about which server you are using.

If you are using PHP, it is pretty much simple, once you have set up a secure connection you just need to send the response in the following manner:

```
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Some Message";
die(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not asking about server side,I'm asking about android side,server side wants to receive array not like [some array]=>some value, but like this ARRAY([some array]=>"some value ") and it seems like its impossible i don't know

Comment: and he wants to receive it like this from me(android side)

Comment: I am still not able to understand what you want here. Do you want to send a POST request from Android and receive a response?

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();


        JSONArray taskDoneJsonArray= new JSONArray();
taskDoneJsonArray.add("aa");
        JSONArray nextStepsJsonArray= new JSONArray();
nextStepsJsonArray.add("bb");

        try {
            jsonObject.put("accessToken", "something");
            jsonObject.put("taskDone",taskDoneJsonArray);
            jsonObject.put("nextTask",nextStepsJsonArray);
            jsonObject.put("issueRemaining",issuesQueriesJsonArray);
        }
        catch (JSONException jsonException){
            ToastMessage.show(context,context.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.error)+jsonException.getMessage());
        }
```

Now use jsonObject

Comment: sorry but please do read,he don't want to use json:(like i don't know why he just want to receive array from me in the way of like ARRAY([somevalueheadr]=>"some value" )